# How to recover If you lost administrator rights of Google Apps?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I tried of Google Apps Premier Edition, but I got rid of administrator rights of the administrative account by mistake and was not able to access Control Panel.

How to recover If you lost administrator rights of Google Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've lost access to the account with administrative rights, I'm afraid your only solution will be to contact google support.